# Stop child thread from main thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm starting a webserver in a new thread. After all tests are run I want to kill the child thread with running server inside. The only one solution is interrupting entire process with all threads inside by calling "*os.system('kill %d' % os.getpid())*" (see the code below). I'm not sure it's the smartest solution. I'm not sure all threads will be killed after all. Could I send some kind of "Keyboard interrupt" signal to stop the thread before exiting main thread?

```
import http
import os
import sys
import unittest
import time

import requests
import threading

from addresses import handle_get_addresses, load_addresses
from webserver import HTTPHandler


def run_in_thread(fn):
    def run(*k, **kw):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=k, kwargs=kw)
        t.start()
        return t
    return run


@run_in_thread
def start_web_server():
    web_host = 'localhost'
    print("starting server...")
    web_port = 8808
    httpd = http.server.HTTPServer((web_host, web_port), HTTPHandler)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


class TestAddressesApi(unittest.TestCase):

    WEB_SERVER_THREAD: threading.Thread = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.WEB_SERVER_THREAD = start_web_server()
        pass

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print("shutting down the webserver...")
        # here someting like cls.WEB_SERVER_THREAD.terminate() 
        # instead of line below
        os.system('kill %d' % os.getpid())

    def test_get_all_addresses(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

Comment: my child thread is not capable to check any flags. it's busy with running webserver. It's sort of locked with endless loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution. Daemon Threads stop executing when main thread stops working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#id6) is you wanted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).